# Count of specific column value in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a column "Call Status" which contains two values (Scheduled and Completed). I want to create two measure. Measure1 contains count of scheduled  and Measure2 contains count of completed against department column.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to create this kind of measure is this:

```
CountOfScheduled = calculate(countrows('YourTable'), FILTER(ALL('YourTable'[Department],'YourTable'[Call Status]), 'YourTable'[Call Status] = "Scheduled" && 'YourTable'[Department] = SELECTEDVALUE('YourTable'[Department]) ))
```

Put department and this measure to TableVisualization.

EDIT:

// for case from comment //

Add a new column in your Table (if posible), by concatenating Department name with Status Name. If not, then create new table for each combination of Department and Status plus KEY to DepartmentTable and Status:

[image]

For this dummy data a New Column:

```
DepartmentAndStatus = 'Table'[Department] & " " & 'Table'[Status]
```

Measure:

```
countOfStatus = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'), FILTER(ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Month]), 'Table'[DepartmentAndStatus]= SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[DepartmentAndStatus]) ))
```

As you can see I put Month on Axis, New column "DepartmentAndStatus" on Legend and Measure to the Value.

Comment: Thanks @msta42a it's working fine but i want to visualize in Bar chart or combo chart e.g x-axis= Month and y-axis= count of "scheduled" and "Completed" and legend wise="Department" is this possible?

Comment: If you put department to the "legend" this measure should still work (split by deparment);

Comment: I tried but didn't work on my case. I used "Line and clustered column chart" to create this, I put 2 calculated measure on column values and x-axis=Month when I put legend on column values it doesn't allow to put legend when I put 2 measure on column values that's the issue I'm facing.  is there any alternate way? awaiting your response ASAP thanks @msta42a

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: thanks a ton will try it  @msta42a