# How do I create a column in PowerBI that displays the count of a specific value

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset in PowerBI that uses many specific date values. I would like to create a new column that gives the count of the date value in its specific row, throughout the dataset. For example, the first few rows might look like this:

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| June 29, 2022 | 2 |
| July 8, 2006 | 1 |
| June 29, 2022 | 2 |
| December 15, 2019 | 1 |

And I am trying to write code for the Count column.

I have already tried using the COUNT and COUNTROWS functions as well as an adaption of the following code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617630/count-of-specific-column-value-in-powerbi) (all to no avail):

```
CountOfScheduled = calculate(countrows('YourTable'), FILTER(ALL('YourTable'[Department],'YourTable'[Call Status]), 'YourTable'[Call Status] = "Scheduled" && 'YourTable'[Department] = SELECTEDVALUE('YourTable'[Department]) ))
```

This function might work fine if you only have a few values and can type each one into the formula, but I have many values. I don't want to type in every single date in the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need a calculated column

```
Column =
CALCULATE ( COUNT ( 'fact'[Date] ), ALLEXCEPT ( 'fact', 'fact'[Date] ) )
```

[image: S1]

**`ALLEXCEPT`** is a means of defining partition, fact[date] in this case.

If you meant a measure

```
Measure = CALCULATE(COUNT('fact'[Date]),ALL('fact'),VALUES('fact'[Date]))
```

[image: S1]

Comment: Thanks. The measure gave me the correct numbers, but the column gave me the correct numbers squared for some reason.

Comment: The answer was based on the sample you provided. If you have a different sample where you have unexpected results, please create a new question with complete sample data.

Comment: I did change the column and table names to fit my data. Afterwards I tried to recreate the sample dataset in this question. But it still came out the same: the measure got it right, whereas the column gave me the answer squared. (At least, in the Table in Report view. In Data view the column is correct.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EARLIER` *(or `EARLIEST`)* to refer to the matching item in the same row.

So:

```
Count = countrows(filter('Table (3)','Table (3)'[Date]=EARLIER([Date])))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this method, but it didn't work. It told me there was something wrong with the EARLIER function syntax, that it couldn't find the [Date] column. I then tried including the table name and switching to using the EARLIEST function, but neither worked.

Comment: @JoeG. The code was based on the information you show.  You need to change the table name to your actual table name, and the column names to the actual names, using the syntax shown.

Comment: I did replace the table name and the column name in my project. Then I tried recreating the example I gave with this exact grid, called "Table" instead of "Table (3)". It's giving me an error message that says "Token Literal expected." When I click "Show error" it highlights the "e" at the end of the first 'Table'. Perhaps we are using different versions?

Comment: Maybe try using IntelliSense to enter the table name instead of typing it? From the screenshot, you can see that it works here.